# What stops me from increasing the degree of my polynomial regression in Matlab? Is there a limit?

Tags: matlab, regression, polynomials

I don't have a very large data set. I want to use polynomial regression, on less than hundred sets with several thousand (6 to 25) data points. A polynomial regression of degree 35 is giving me a pretty good result when I plot it comparing to the original data. Is there anything wrong with increasing the degree, for example to 35? (Using Matlab polyfit, I'm trying on one of the smaller vectors, around 9k data points.)

Comment: Yes, the problem can be overfitting your data. A polynomial of order N-1 will fit your N data points with zero error. But you will have massive overfitting

Comment: [Nice diagram from google](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1125/1*_7OPgojau8hkiPUiHoGK_w.png)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, one problem is overfitting. Another problem is, however, the shape. Increasing polynom degree also forces the function to have more minima, maxima, turnpoints.

In fact, you might want to use splines instead of increasing degree. These functions are piecewise low degree polynomials fitted such that first derivative coincides on borders of pieces. This is a way to apply polynomial interpolation to large and complex data.

Comment: That is true, but they are more free in placing them. You avoid the oscillating behavior.